# How deep does the findstr command go if you run it in the C:/ drive?

Tags: windows, shell, file, command-line, findstr

So I have been recently doing HackTheBox and am working on some of their starter labs. In one of them, the answer to find the root password is through finding this hidden subfolder within one of the User directories.

Before I looked at the answer to the problem I had run the following command:

`findstr /s /p /i /m <admin.* *.*`

as well as

`findstr /s /p /i /m administrator *.*`

Which in both cases should:

- /s : Search the current directory and all subdirectories
- /p : Skip files with non-printable characters
- /i : Ignore the case of the word
- /m : Print only the filename if a file contains a match

When I ran this from the C:/ drive, it returned many files but not the one that had the root password in it. I eventually gave in and viewed the answer and I was on the right track ("administrator" was in the file) but I am wondering why it didn't find it when I ran it in the C:/ drive.

I ran the same command again, this time in the basic user folder ( C:/Users/ ) and it did find it.

I just assumed that since the /s command searches through ALL subdirectories that I would have found the file in that route. If someone might be able to explain why this didn't work, I would love to know why.